# Reference for a clear version of multigraded Serre-Grothendieck-Deligne correspondence local cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, local-cohomology

The Grothendieck-Serre-Deligne correspondence states the following.  Let $ R $ be a Noetherian, graded ring and let $ T $ be $ \operatorname{Proj}(R) $.  If $ \mathcal{F} $ is a coherent sheaf on $ T $, then there is a finitely generated, graded $ R $-module $ N $ such that $ \mathcal{F} $ is isomorphic to the sheaf of $ \mathcal{O}_{T} $-modules associated to $ N $ on $ T $.  The Grothendieck-Serre-Deligne correspondence now yields that $ H^{i}(T, \mathcal{F}(n)) \cong H^{i+1}_{R_{+}}(N)_{n} $.

I have seen other authors reference a multigraded version of the Grothendieck-Serre-Deligne correspondence.  Does anyone have a reference where this correspondence is clearly stated and/or proved?